# Looping through multiple xml, adding to listView

Tags: java, android, xml, rss

I have followed a tutorial which shows you how you can connect to an rss feed, and pull down the data into a listView. The problem is, is that I want to be able to loop through multiple feeds adding them to the same listView, but when I try to do this....it brings back the following logCat error.

If anyone can help me, that would be great thanks!

Code:

```
package com.androidhive.xmlparsing;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidXMLParsingActivity extends ListActivity {

    // All static variables
    //static final String URL = "http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/sport/0/football/rss.xml?edition=uk";
    String[] URL = new String[2];
    int count = 0;
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_ITEM = "item"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    static final String KEY_COST = "cost";
    static final String KEY_DESC = "description";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        rssRun();

    }



    public void rssRun()
    {
        URL[0] = "http://www.skysports.com/rss/0,20514,11661,00.xml";
        URL[1] = "http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/sport/0/football/rss.xml?edition=uk";
        for (int f= 0;f < 2;f++)
        {
            count+=1;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL[f]); // getting XML
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
        // looping through all item nodes <item>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
            map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
            map.put(KEY_COST, parser.getValue(e, KEY_COST));
            map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            menuItems.add(map);
        }


        // Adding menuItems to ListView
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
                R.layout.list_item,
                new String[] { KEY_NAME, KEY_DESC, KEY_COST }, new int[] {
                        R.id.name, R.id.desciption, R.id.cost });
        if (count==2)
        {
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }

        // selecting single ListView item
        ListView lv = getListView();

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
                String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cost)).getText().toString();
                String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desciption)).getText().toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
                in.putExtra(KEY_NAME, name);
                in.putExtra(KEY_COST, cost);
                in.putExtra(KEY_DESC, description);
                startActivity(in);

            }
        });
    }
    }

}
```

LogCat:

```
08-27 09:34:39.786: E/Error:(30651): Expected a quoted string (position:DOCDECL @1:50 in java.io.StringReader@42be4218) 
08-27 09:34:39.786: D/AndroidRuntime(30651): Shutting down VM
08-27 09:34:39.786: W/dalvikvm(30651): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41966da0)
08-27 09:34:39.786: E/AndroidRuntime(30651): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-27 09:34:39.786: E/AndroidRuntime(30651): Process: com.androidhive.xmlparsing, PID: 30651
08-27 09:34:39.786: E/AndroidRuntime(30651): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidhive.xmlparsing/com.androidhive.xmlparsing.AndroidXMLParsingActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-27 09:34:39.786: E/AndroidRuntime(30651):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
08-27 09:34:39.786: E/AndroidRuntime(30651):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
08-27 09:34:39.786: E/AndroidRuntime(30651):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
08-27 09:34:39.786: E/AndroidRuntime(30651):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
08-27 09:34:39.786: E/AndroidRuntime(30651):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-27 09:34:39.786: E/AndroidRuntime(30651):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
08-27 09:34:39.786: E/AndroidRuntime(30651):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
08-27 09:34:39.786: E/AndroidRuntime(30651):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-27 09:34:39.786: E/AndroidRuntime(30651):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-27 09:34:39.786: E/AndroidRuntime(30651):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
08-27 09:34:39.786: E/AndroidRuntime(30651):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
08-27 09:34:39.786: E/AndroidRuntime(30651):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-27 09:34:39.786: E/AndroidRuntime(30651): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-27 09:34:39.786: E/AndroidRuntime(30651):    at com.androidhive.xmlparsing.AndroidXMLParsingActivity.rssRun(AndroidXMLParsingActivity.java:57)
08-27 09:34:39.786: E/AndroidRuntime(30651):    at com.androidhive.xmlparsing.AndroidXMLParsingActivity.onCreate(AndroidXMLParsingActivity.java:38)
08-27 09:34:39.786: E/AndroidRuntime(30651):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5426)
08-27 09:34:39.786: E/AndroidRuntime(30651):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
08-27 09:34:39.786: E/AndroidRuntime(30651):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
```

Comment: line at 38 and 57 of AndroidXMLParsingActivity.java ?

Comment: Hmm, I think I have narrowed it down to the feed I give it. If I give it some feeds, it does not add them. However, if I give it other feeds it does add them. I think it is only adding feeds with the 'xml' suffix on the end of the URL.